# vlookup in sql and removing duplicates

Tags: sql

table A with unique cust id

[image]

table B with cust_id and a column dealer/direct

[image]

desired output

[image]

im trying to vlookup dealer/direct from table B to table A in SQL

Conditions:

```
if a customer is dealer i have to take dealer
if a customer is direct i have to take direct
if a customer is both dealer and direct i have to take direct only
```

is there anyway in sql to do this.. i did this in sql using pivots and vlookup

Comment: don't post link  ...  post sample data and expected  result as tabular text

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different RDBMS, what are you really using? `vlookup` is a Worksheet function; tables (in databases) aren't worksheet. What you are after is a `JOIN`. These are one of the fundamental parts of learning SQL, and I suggest you start by reading up on the basics of the language. You'll learn far more that way.

Comment: @larnu can you do this using joins..i desire the get the same output as excel vlookup in sql

Comment: I haven't looked at your links, @Kunal, however, a `vlookup` is, effectively, the worksheet equivalent of a SQL `JOIN`. Like i said, I suggest reading up on the fundamentals of SQL; there are plenty of guides and tutorials out there for beginners. You'll learn much more than way. You'll also, however, need to actually work out what RDBMS you're using, as you've tagged 2 very different ones.

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, MAX()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method is aggregation:

```
select a.cust_id, a.name, max(b.col)
from a join
     b
     on a.cust_id = b.cust_id
group by a.cust_id, a.name;
```

This works because `'direct'` > `'dealer'` (under any reasonable collation), so `max()` will return `'direct'` if any values are direct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.XYZ 
FROM a 
JOIN b on a.id = b.id
```